# Hibernate returns null for entity property that is annotated with @Formula after saving the entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, formula

I have simple class as you can see below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    String title;

    @Formula("(select current_date())")
    Date currentDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    Set<PostComment> commentList = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and want to update this entity in the service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PostService {

    private final PostRepository postRepository;

    public PostService(PostRepository postRepository) {
        this.postRepository = postRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Post save(Post entity) {
        Post post = postRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
        System.out.println("current_date: " + post.getCurrentDate());
        post.getCommentList().forEach(pc -> System.out.println(pc.getReview()));
        return post;
    }
}
```

And when i check hibernate logs, it first `select` all fields of `Post` entity but when i call `post.getCurrentDate()` (that it annotated with `@Formula`) returns `null`:

```
Hibernate: select post0_.id as id1_0_0_, post0_.title as title2_0_0_, (select current_date()) as formula0_0_ from post post0_ where post0_.id=?
Hibernate: update post set title=? where id=?
current_date: null
Hibernate: select commentlis0_.post_id as post_id3_1_0_, commentlis0_.id as id1_1_0_, commentlis0_.id as id1_1_1_, commentlis0_.post_id as post_id3_1_1_, commentlis0_.review as review2_1_1_ from post_comments commentlis0_ where commentlis0_.post_id=?
review
```

Why it returns and logs `commentList` but doesn't return `currentDate`? is it hibernate bug?

**NOTE**

I pushed the complete sample project in the github you can see [here](https://github.com/rasoolghafari/spring-data-jpa-save-flush/blob/309c2a665eb5174846e66f4e11e8377d0e633956/src/main/java/com/example/demo/service/PostService.java#L24).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote [a test case on my high-performance-java-persistence GitHub repository](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/951db3fb0f6e9e699d4023044aa6baaeaec54696/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/mapping/calculated/FormulaCurrentDateTest.java) which works like a charm.

The entity looks as follows:

```
@Entity(name = "Event")
@Table(name = "event")
public static class Event {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Formula("(SELECT current_date)")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }
}
```

Notice that the `Date` property uses the `@Temporal` annotation as well.

Now to emulate your use case, I wrote the following data access logic:

```
Event event = new Event();
event.setId(1L);

entityManager.persist(event);
entityManager.flush();

entityManager.refresh(event);

assertNotNull(event.getCreatedOn());
```

Notice the `refresh` call which is needed since the entity is cached upon `persist`, and we want to refetch it anew from the DB.

And, when executing it, Hibernate generates the following statements:

```
Query:["insert into event (id) values (?)"], Params:[(1)]
Query:["select formulacur0_.id as id1_0_0_, (SELECT current_date) as formula0_0_ from event formulacur0_ where formulacur0_.id=?"], Params:[(1)]
```

And the test case runs just fine. Just do a comparison debug between your use case and mine and see why yours doesn't work and mine does.

Comment: If you check hibernate logs, it select all columns, also `select current_date()` but why does not set to `currentDate` field?

Comment: `@Generated` is used to calculate and save value for a column, but i want to make calculation it only when load object. what should i debug it?

Comment: Run the query in debug mode and check out what the JDBC ResultSet contains.

Comment: This is result of query `select post0_.id as id1_0_0_, post0_.title as title2_0_0_, (select current_date()) as formula0_0_ from post post0_ where post0_.id=?`, it select all columns

Comment: I updated my answer with a reference to a test case on GitHub which works just fine.

Comment: You're right. After calling the refresh method, the query is executed again and the formula is set to the field. But the thing that involves my mind is that once the merge is called, it executes the formulas column once. Why is this attribute not set after the execution and receipt of information from the database side. Do not hibernate read this value from the results and set it to feild? Do you think this does not cause performance problems?